# What is the best practice for indicating / rendering error and success in a Blazor Server app with external calls?

Tags: c#, user-interface, error-handling, blazor-server-side, cqrs

This is more of a general question than a Blazor specific one.

I am writing a Blazor server application which serves as the UI for CRUD operations on data in my SQL DB. These CRUD operations are implemented through command and queries in an application layer. On the UI, I would like to render error/success messages based on the result of the application layer command or query.

I'm curious what others feel is the most appropriate way to do this?

Here is some pseudo-code for what I've currently implemented:

```
try 
{
   Task updateTask = appService.UpdateEntity(entity);
   await updateTask;

   if (updateTask.RanToCompletion) 
      { Display("Command completed successfully", Color.Success); }
}
catch
{
   Display("Error: Could not update entity.", Color.Error);
}
```

Here, the `UpdateEntity` method returns a `Task`. I know that exceptions are not supposed to be used for application logic, but using an exception in this way is acceptable right?

Would it be better to have `UpdateEntity` return `Task<bool>`? If so, would I return true on success and throw an exception otherwise?

Would it be better to have `UpdateEntity` return some object used as different error / success codes?

I'm curious how other developers would handle this.

Comment: I personally would throw a specific exception when the update failed. Catch that exception log it and display an appropiate error message. If the Update is likely to fail for what ever reasons one could have a TryUpdate() method returning a bool. I like to have update methods return the edited entity because some propertys might have changed. But void might be OK too depending on your app.